# Under "Tweaks > Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options > Alt/Win key behavior", what does the "Disabled" option mean?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweak-tool

I may be overthinking it, but I can't find anything that looks like the default option under

**Tweaks > Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options > Alt/Win key behavior**

[image: Keyboard Options > Additional Layout Options]

The title of the menu suggests that it deals with either  <kbd>alt</kbd>  or  <kbd>win</kbd> . This assumes I understand what is meant by  <kbd>/</kbd> . Did the writer may have meant *both*  <kbd>alt</kbd>  *and*  <kbd>win</kbd> ?

The first option under **Alt/Win key behavior** menu the is **Disabled**.

Does that mean that those keys are disabled? Does it mean that there is some shared behavior that is disabled when the bubble is selected?

If I am looking for the standard Windows style behavior for  <kbd>alt</kbd>  and  <kbd>win</kbd> , which bubble would I select?

The other options seem to change the standard behavior. I'm looking for an option that says "Alt is Alt and Win is Super" or eve "Alt is Alt and Win is Super" or even a "Default" bubble.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled means that no XKB option, which changes the behavior of the Win/Super key, is set. It reasonably means that Win/Super behaves in accordance with the default configuration of your desktop environment.